# MySQL JSON column add new array as element

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a table with JSON type column, I want to update a column with new array element in existing JSON.

**What needs to be done:** add an array in JSON column when employee punch_in and add another array in JSON column when employee punch_out.

```
{"emp_sheet":[{"rulecode":"PUNCH_IN","result":1,"applytime":"2018-04-12 04:50:39"},{"rulecode":"PUNCH_OUT","result":1,"applytime":"2018-04-12 13:01:39"}]}
```

What I did, for employee punch_in:

```
UPDATE table 
SET rule_codes = JSON_SET(COALESCE(rule_codes, '{}'), '$.emp_sheet', '{"rulecode":"PUNCH_IN","result":1,"applytime":"2018-04-12 04:50:39"}') 
WHERE emp_id = 1
```

Result in rule_codes column =

`{"emp_sheet": "{"rulecode":"PUNCH_IN","result":1,"applytime":"2018-04-12 04:50:39"}"}`

Please help me to write update query for employee punch_out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND` instead of `JSON_SET`.

Manual - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html

I think it could be like this

```
rule_codes = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(COALESCE(rule_codes, '{"emp_sheet":[]}'), '$.emp_sheet', '{"rulecode":"PUNCH_IN","result":1,"applytime":"2018-04-12 04:50:39"}')
```

or

```
rule_codes = IF(rule_codes IS NULL,'
    '{"emp_sheet":[{"rulecode":"PUNCH_IN","result":1,"applytime":"2018-04-12 04:50:39"}]}',
    JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(rule_codes, '$.emp_sheet', '{"rulecode":"PUNCH_IN","result":1,"applytime":"2018-04-12 04:50:39"}')
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be easiest if you made `$.emp_sheet` a JSON array on punch in:

```
UPDATE table3
SET rule_codes = JSON_SET(COALESCE(rule_codes, JSON_OBJECT('emp_sheet', JSON_ARRAY())), 
                          '$.emp_sheet[0]', 
                          '{"rulecode":"PUNCH_IN","result":1,"applytime":"2018-04-12 04:50:39"}') 
WHERE emp_id = 1
```

Then on punch out, you can add another element to the array:

```
UPDATE table3
SET rule_codes = JSON_SET(COALESCE(rule_codes, JSON_OBJECT('emp_sheet', JSON_ARRAY())),
                          '$.emp_sheet[1]',
                          '{"rulecode":"PUNCH_OUT","result":1,"applytime":"2018-04-12 13:01:39"}') 
WHERE emp_id = 1;

SELECT rule_codes FROM table3 WHERE emp_id = 1
```

Output:

```
{"emp_sheet": [
    "{\"rulecode\":\"PUNCH_IN\",\"result\":1,\"applytime\":\"2018-04-12 04:50:39\"}", 
    "{\"rulecode\":\"PUNCH_OUT\",\"result\":1,\"applytime\":\"2018-04-12 13:01:39\"}"
 ]}
```

Note that when you do the SET, the input JSON (`'{"rulecode ... }'`) gets treated as a string, hence the escaped `"` in the output above. You can remove those with `JSON_UNQUOTE` when you extract i.e.

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(rule_codes, '$.emp_sheet[0]')) FROM `table3`
```

or using the short-cut notation

```
SELECT rule_codes->>'$.emp_sheet[0]' FROM `table3`
```

Output:

```
{"rulecode":"PUNCH_IN","result":1,"applytime":"2018-04-12 04:50:39"}
```